# capitalize first letter and strip html code

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following html page:
What I am looking to do is capitalize the first letter (which is working without any issue) and strip the textbox of any html code or any code that has a combincation of "<" "/>" ">" so user cannot insert malicious code to execute at server end.

I found a code which strips:

```
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

How do I add the above code to the below page so it takes care of both?

```
<?php
/**
 * ****************************************************************************
 * Micro Protector
 * 
 * Version: 1.0
 * Release date: 2007-09-10
 * 
 * USAGE:
 *   Define your requested password below and inset the following code
 *   at the beginning of your page:
 *   <?php require_once("microProtector.php"); ?>
 * 
 *  
 * 
 ******************************************************************************/


$Password = 'TESTPASS'; // Set your password here



/******************************************************************************/
   if (isset($_POST['submit_pwd'])){
      $pass = isset($_POST['passwd']) ? $_POST['passwd'] : '';

      if ($pass != $Password) {
         showForm("Wrong password");
         exit();     
      }
   } else {
      showForm();
      exit();
   }

function showForm($error="LOGIN"){
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
   <title>IMC - Authentication</title>
   <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<Script>
<!--
function capitalize(form) {
    value = form.value;
    newValue = '';
    value = value.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        newValue += value[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() +
        value[i].substring(1,value[i].length) + '';
    }
form.value = newValue;
}
-->
</Script>
</head>
<body>
<center><a href="http://www.test.com"><img src="test.png" border=0 /></a></center>
<br><br><br>
    <div id="main">
      <div class="caption"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
      <div id="icon">&nbsp;</div>
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="pwd">
    Your Name:
        <table>
          <tr><td><input class="text" name="name" onBlur="capitalize(this);" maxlength=12 type="text" /></td></tr>
        </table> 
        Password:
        <table>
          <tr><td><input class="text" name="passwd" maxlength=8 type="password" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td align="center"><br/>
             <input class="text" type="submit" name="submit_pwd" value="Login" />
          </td></tr>
        </table>  
      </form>
   </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php   
}
?>
```

Comment: Capitalize the first letter only or the first letter of each word?

Comment: its a name so i am only capitalizing the first letter.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in your code, is it possible that the tag selected is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `newValue = newValue.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");` before `form.value = newValue;`

Comment: OriginalString was just an example variable. Should i replace that with NewValue?

Comment: I added and it only capitalizes but does not remove the "<" as test

Comment: It won't remove a single angle bracket. It will remove whole tags. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdKEC/);

Comment: I know what you mean. That works fine. Thanks! Now only if I can securely send the data to the server. Any idea? I update my question if you can take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope you realise that any malicious user can just bypass your function completely. All I'd have to do is put `capitalize=function(){}` in my console and all of a sudden I can write what I want... Or I could just disable JavaScript. Either way I can send anything I like to your server.

On the server side, you should use a function like PHP's [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to prevent HTML from being injected into a user's browser, and while you're at it you can use [`ucfirst`](http://php.net/ucfirst) to capitalise the first letter (or [`ucwords`](http://php.net/ucwords) for the first letter of every word).

Comment: I will post the page, so you can make recommendation based on what I have. It doesn't send anything to server persay. But let me update the contents and let me know. Thanks

Comment: `<form>`... it sends data to the server.